# ASP.NET WebAPI 2 deserializing JSON sets some nested objects to null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, deserialization, asp.net-web-api2

I am encountering an issue while sending some JSON from an AngularJS application to a ASP.Net WebAPI 2 back-end. What happens is that some properties from the incoming request are set to null during deserialization.

Part of the request where the deserialization bug occurs:

```
12: {row: 9, column: 1, order: 13,…}
column: 1
domainEntityProperty: {$id: "157", id: 2616,…}
order: 13
renderType: {$id: "39", id: 1, class: "input"}
row: 9
```

Above snippet is piece of the request that is being sent. It's a so called `screen property` being saved. The request has an array of these objects. The strange thing is that everything is deserialized just fine when a maximum of one new screen property is added per request. When more than one is added, the `domainEntityProperty` and `renderType` properties are set to null on deserializing.

This is the model to which the JSON is converted in the controller:

```
public class ScreenPropertyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public RenderTypeModel RenderType { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }

    public int Row { get; set; }

    public int Column { get; set; }

    public DomainPropertyModel DomainEntityProperty { get; set; }
}
```

An example of the object after deserializing:

```
ScreenPropertyModel
-------------------
 - Column = 1,
 - Row = 9,
 - Order = 13,
 - DomainEntityProperty = null,
 - RenderType = null
```

Does anybody know why the `DomainEntityProperty` and `RenderType` properties are `null`? And more specifically: why does this only happen when multiple new objects are being saved?

I'd be thankful if anyone could point me in the right direction here.

### Update ## - `DomainProperty` and `RenderType` definitions

DomainProperty:

```
public class DomainPropertyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // some more simple properties

    public IList<DefaultValueModel> DefaultValues { get; set; }

    public IList<ScreenPropertyModel> ScreenProperties { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BusinessRuleProperty> BusinessRuleProperties { get; set; }
}
```

RenderType:

```
public class RenderTypeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Class { get; set; }
}
```

As far as I can see in Chrome developer tools, all these properties are present on the object that is being sent to the server.

Comment: Which MVC version are you using? Or which custom serializer?

Comment: and the definitions of `RenderTypeModel`  and `DomainPropertyModel` are as expected? Perhaps you should also post them.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Sorry, meant WebAPI instead of MVC. More specifically: WebAPI2 with NewtonSoft.Json.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Updated the OP with the definitions of ``RenderTypeModel`` and ``DomainPropertyModel``.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you get it fixed?

Comment: @Vector If I recall correctly I solved it by turning reference loop handling off in the `StartUp`, i.e.:  `var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings; settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;`